# How to open a link in browser from gedit?

Tags: gedit, plugins, url

I have some text files that contains some links/url. I would like to open the link/url in firefox or chrome when I click (left mouse click) the link. Is that possible?

So far I have tried to add a plugin by copying the files in `/usr/share/gedit/plugins/` but in the plugin preference in gedit no new plugin shows.

Comment: A shortcut would be quite easy to accomplish. Either gedit- specific or general. Would that do?

Answer (score 9):

This can be done with the nice gedit plugin `open-uri-context-menu`. I have tested this plugin on the three supported LTS releases:

1. Xenial Xerus LTS (gedit 3.18.3)
2. Trusty Tahr LTS (gedit 3.10.4)
3. Precise Pangolin LTS (gedit 3.4.1)

Installation instructions are *slightly different* for each LTS release as a different version of the plugin is required for each. Select the appropriate version for *your* setup from the three given below:

**1. Installation: Xenial Xerus**

Xenial ships with gedit 3.18.3 and to install *Version 3* of the plugin download and install as follows:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/open_uri && cd ~/Desktop/open_uri
wget https://github.com/jpfleury/open-uri-context-menu/archive/master.zip
mkdir -pv ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
unzip -j master.zip 'open-uri-context-menu-master/open-uri*' -d ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
```

**2. Installation: Trusty Tahr**

Trusty ships with gedit 3.10.4 and to install *Version 2* of the plugin download and install as follows:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/open_uri && cd ~/Desktop/open_uri
wget https://github.com/jpfleury/open-uri-context-menu/archive/v2.zip
mkdir -pv ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
unzip -j v2.zip 'open-uri-context-menu-2/open-uri*' -d ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
```

**3. Installation: Precise Pangolin**

Precise ships with gedit 3.4.1 and to install *Version 1* of the plugin download and install as follows:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/open_uri && cd ~/Desktop/open_uri
wget https://github.com/jpfleury/open-uri-context-menu/archive/v1.zip
mkdir -pv ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
unzip -j v1.zip 'open-uri-context-menu-1/open-uri*' -d ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
```

**4. Setup for Xenial, Trusty and Precise:**

Then on any of the LTS releases open gedit and navigate to the 'Plugins' screen by following this trail:

```
 Edit > Preferences > Plugins
```

and then *activate* the plugin by ensuring there is a 'tick' or 'check' mark next to the plugin description as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Now when you *right* click on a link (admittedly not *left* click as you specified) within a document opened with gedit you will see the following options:

[image]

The two plugin options seen here are:

1. **Browse to**: Open the link in an *external* browser such as Firefox
2. **Open**: Open the contents of the link *within* another gedit window

Works nicely on each of my Xenial, Trusty and Precise systems and should on yours as well...

**References:**

- [jpfleury/open-uri-context-menu](https://github.com/jpfleury/open-uri-context-menu)

Comment: While this is clearly the answer in this specific situation, you could also do something like this using a macro written in AutoKey https://github.com/autokey/autokey. This requires more effort, but would also work with some other editor or program which did not have such a capability or plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions* of gedit have the appropriate plugin **built-in**. Simply go to ☰ → Preferences → Plugins and enable "Open Links".

You can then right-click any link and a new context menu entry "Open Link" will be at the very top.

[image: screenshot highlighting the described plugin in the list]

*It was added in gedit 42, maybe a bit earlier.

Comment: I don't have the "Open Links" plugin in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @user68186 Looks like it was added in Debian 12 (bookworm), compare (libopenlinks.so): https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/i386/gedit/filelist vs https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/i386/gedit/filelist -- I'm not sure which Ubuntu added it, but I'm on PopOS 22.04 and have it.